# response from the com port indefinitely

Tags: c#, serial-port

I work with com port
faced with a problem, send a request to the com port and waiting for an answer. the answer is infinite ...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             byte[] cahs;
             byte[] cash_with_bbc;
            SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            mySerialPort.Open();
            cahs = new byte[] { 0x04, 0x30, 0x02, 0x44, 0x03 };
            cash_with_bbc = new byte[] { 0x04, 0x30, 0x02, 0x44, 0x03, GetBCC(cahs) };
            mySerialPort.Write(cash_with_bbc, 0, cash_with_bbc.Length);

            Thread.Sleep(50);

            Console.WriteLine(mySerialPort.ReadLine());

            while (mySerialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mySerialPort.ReadLine());
            }

            mySerialPort.Write(new byte[] {0x06}, 0, 1);

            mySerialPort.Close();
        }
        private static byte GetBCC(byte[] inputStream)
        {
            byte bcc = 0;

            if (inputStream != null && inputStream.Length > 0)
            {
                // Exclude SOH during BCC calculation
                for (int i = 0; i < inputStream.Length; i++)
                {
                    bcc ^= inputStream[i];
                }
            }

            return bcc;
        }
```

documentation

> Cash dispenser is operated by the
>   command from upper level device (host)
>   and sends the response for that. When
>   cash dispenser receives a command, the
>   response should be sent before the
>   next command is received. If a command
>   sends during the processing the
>   response, cash dispenser would not
>   react and respond to the command at
>   all. Also cash dispenser doesn’t give
>   any response before a command is
>   arrived.
>
> When a message (command or response)
>   has been sent, a response is sent to
>   indicate whether the message has been
>   successfully received.
>
> ACK (0x06): to indicate that message
>   has been accepted.  NAK (0x15): to
>   indicate that the message has been
>   rejected and that the message should
>   be resent.
>
> The re-sending of one message will be
>   tried up to 3 times and, in case all
>   of the trials fail, the message will
>   be canceled and new transmission mode
>   be ready. All the texts except ACK
>   would be considered as NAK.
>   (Exceptionally. EOT (0x04) is the
>   newly sent character set from upper
>   level and it is recognized as EOT
>   which enables to be ready for new
>   communication transferring mode.)
>
> Every message has Block Check
>   Character (BCC), which shows whether
>   the message is normal or abnormal.
>   Therefore, in case of right BCC, the
>   message is known as normal state
>   (Sending ACK). Otherwise, NAK is sent
>   and notice the failure of message
>   transmission. The character set of EOT
>   is used in the head and the end of the
>   message. If it is not located on BCC
>   Check, all the transmission order is
>   ignored and new communication mode is
>   set up.

Comment: "the answer is infinite ..." - I thought it was 42....

Answer (score 0):

The device might respond with a NewLine that does not match the one that expect `Serial.RaedLine()`. From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.newline.aspx) default is `LF`, try with `CR` or even `CRLF`:

```
mySerialPort.NewLine = "\r";
```

Comment: I added documentation. Look plz